# Easiest way to display specific value from reddit comments .json file?

Tags: json, display, reddit

Is there a simple way to display on my website a specific value, for example "Gonna make this my new alarm ringtone" from following reddit comments .json file: https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/mi0lic/.json

I've found a simple php script that works with reddit user .json files:

```
... $content = file_get_contents("https://www.reddit.com/user/joshfolgado/about.json");
$result  = json_decode($content);
print_r( $result->data->subreddit->title ); ...
```

But I can't make this work using the comments .json file:

```
... $content = file_get_contents("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/mi0lic/.json");
$result  = json_decode($content);
print_r( $result->data->children->data->title ); ...
```

Any other simple script that does the job is also welcome.

Comment: I found it might be better to use https://api.reddit.com/api/info/?id=t3_mi0lic instead to get rid of all a possible very long list of replies in a comment, so the script would look more like:...$content = file_get_contents("https://api.reddit.com/api/info/?id=t3_mi0lic"); $result = json_decode($content); print_r( $result->data->children->data->title );...

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be found here:

```php
print_r( $result->data->children->data->title ); ...
```

`$result->data->children` is an Array holding **all** the comments returned by the API.

We should 'search' all those comments (in your example, it's just 1) for the desired object.

Consider the following code example we're I've used [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to custom filter the objects found in `$result->data->children` array.

```php
<?php

// Search string
$search = 'Gonna make this my new alarm ringtone';

// Get json using CURL
$json = getJson('t3_mi0lic');

// Search ->children
$res = array_filter($json->data->children, function ($child) use ($search) {

    // Include if ->data->title qeuals search
    return $child->data->title === $search;
});

// Show result
var_dump($res);




// Get JSON by $userId
function getJson($userId) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.reddit.com/api/info/?id=' . $userId,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($response);
}
```